# setTimeout() executed more times?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add functionality to a html/js stopwatch, but i have a problem with setTimeout() function. Why is it only executed once for me, but in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_3059475893&feature=iv&src_vid=iSLWtGAw1Ic&v=gpFPppFU8s8

it is executed until someone stops it. Yeah I know I can use setInterval, but I'm just curious.

here is my code:

```
let running = false;
let time = 0;

function start() {
    running = true;
    timer();
}

function stop() {
    running = false;
}

function reset() {
    running = false;
    time = 0;
    document.getElementById("stw").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}
function timer() {
    if (running) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            time++;
            let min = Math.floor(time / 100 / 60);
            let sec = Math.floor(time / 100) % 60;
            let mSec = time % 100;

            if (min < 10) {
                min = "0" + min;
            }
            if (sec < 10) {
                sec = "0" + sec;
            }
            if (mSec < 10) {
                mSec = "0" + mSec;
            }
            document.getElementById("stw").innerHTML =
                min + ":" + sec + ":" + mSec;
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: What actions are you running - start, stop, reset, etc?

Comment: those are functions binded to html buttons to simply start/stop/reset stopwatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `setTimeout()` to create a loop, inside the function `setTimeout()` calls, you have to call `setTimeout()` again.

Here is a basic loop function that does it:

```js
const loopFunc = () => {
  console.log('loop');
  setTimeout(loopFunc, 1000);
};

loopFunc(); // kick it off
```

Answer (score 0):

In the video (around 2 minutes in), `timer()` calls itself recursively. Your code does not.

Comment: Oh yeah, somehow I missed it. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` only calls its callback function once.

There are two ways to to have it call multiple times:

1. Use `setInterval()`
2. Use a recursive function to restart `setTimeout()` over and over again.

Example:

```
function timer() {
  // do something

  // call this function again in 10 milliseconds
  setTimeout(timer, 10);
}
```